# Getting wrong answer for Merge-Sort in Python2

Tags: python, mergesort

Here is the implementation of merge-sort in python but I'm getting Wrong answer in one of the test cases in hackerrank platform. I don't know where I'm wrong and I don't know the test-case either.

```
def merge(l,r,a):
    nl=len(l)
    nr=len(r)
    i,j,k=0,0,0
    while (i<nl and j<nr):
        if (r[j]<=l[i]):
            a[k]=r[j]
            j=j+1
        else:
            a[k]=l[i]
            i=i+1
        k=k+1
    while (i<nl):
        a[k]=l[i]
        i=i+1
        k=k+1
    while (j<nr):
        a[k]=r[j]
        j=j+1
        k=k+1



def mergesort(a):
    n=len(a)
    if n<2:
        return a
    mid=n/2
    left=a[:mid]
    right=a[mid:]
    mergesort(left)
    mergesort(right)
    merge(left,right,a)
    return a


a=[5,8,3,6,4]
ans=mergesort(a)
for k in ans:
    print k
```

Comment: Your `merge` function appears completely broken. You can't possibly do an in-place merge without passing the start and end of each sublist (and if you're not trying to do it in place you don't need to pass `a`).

Comment: I didn't completely get you, If my merge function is broken then why is it working correctly on my local system with small inputs(that I've tested with)?